# How to run local code on remote host using SSH client?

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

**On SSH Client machine I have following scripts:** 
script.sh 
script-1.sh

**Now... I connect to remote server over ssh with following command:** 
ssh -t @ "$(<./remote.sh)"

**This works fine and I'm able to keep session open ruining following menu from script.sh**

```
PS3='Select number to select script: '
options=("command-1" "script-1" "Quit")
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
    case $opt in
        "command-1")
            ls -l /home/
            ;;
            
        "script-1.sh")
            "script-1.sh"  <<< it is local script on SSH Client not SSH Host
            ;;

        "Quit")
            break
            ;;

        *) echo "invalid option $REPLY";;
    esac
done
exit
```

If I run command-1 from option menu it works perfectly and session does not close.

**Question:**
As above scenario is there a way to run script-1.sh if the script is located on SSH Client not on SSH Host? 
Or maybe there is a better way to accomplish that and rune local scripts from loaded menu on remote ssh host? 

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you can run your local scripts remotely like that:

```
$ ssh <your-server> "bash -s" < ./script-1.sh
```

**Edit** - This is probably a very good related post: [How can I execute local script on remote machine and include arguments?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87406)